# How to PUT to a certain object in a JSON array(npm request)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I'm basically trying to set a value in a JSON array using a PUT request with the request module. The array has multiple main objects, and I only want to set it to one of them. It's in this format:

```
[
   0: {
           status: 'pending'
       }
   1: {
           status: 'pending'
       }
 ]
```

And I'm using this example script from the 'npm request' documentation:

```
request({
method: 'PUT',
preambleCRLF: true,
postambleCRLF: true,
uri: 'http://service.com/upload',
multipart: [
  {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    body: JSON.stringify(-what-goes-in-here-?-
  }
],
function (error, response, body) {
if (error) {
  return console.error('upload failed:', error);
}
console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
 })
```

So the big question is what do I put in "body:" to make it PUT to, say, 0: {status: 'approved'} instead of 1: {status: 'approved'}

I appreciate any help, I can elaborate more if needed. :)

Comment: You need to clarify it further,  what is "body" you're referencing, why is not included ?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you will pass 2 things in your `body` object like this.

```
{
  index: 0, // i.e., object index in array
  status: 'approved' // i.e., status to update
}
```

now, you must be having `upload` route handler, like.

```
app.put('/upload', function(req, res) {
  var index = req.body.index,
      status = req.body.status;

  // update status in your data (Array); 
  // let's say your array is `data`
  data[index].status = status;  // updated.

  res.send('success'); // etc.
})
```